# Get target path before authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, routes

I'm using Devise for user authentication in a rails application, and so certain routes are wrapped in a authenticate tag to allow access only to users who are logged in.

```
authenticate :user do
    post '/user/orders/new', to: 'user/orders#new', as: :new_user_order
end
```

For example, when a user tries to create a new order when they're not logged in, they're redirected to a sign in page.

What I want is for the user to be directed to the new order page after logging in.
Currently, we're using `request.referrer` which redirects the user back to the page they were on before trying to create a new order. I can't seem to figure out a way of getting the path they were targeting before being sent to sign in.

Anybody know how I could do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a before filter for user authentication in the controller and not mention it in routes . Just put the following code in the controller and it should redirect to sign-up if the user isn't logged in -

```
 before_filter :authenticate_user
```

Comment: There's quite a large number of controllers with functionality hidden behind authentication, so I was hoping to get this done in the routes, but if it's not possible, then thanks for the solution.

Comment: Just find out which controller gets called on that particular page . There might be large number of controllers but there will be only one controller for a specific page .

Comment: You will be able to see that in the logs , whenever you will reload the page . You will get to see a controller and the method attached with it .

Comment: Yep, I just meant that there are multiple pages I'd want to do this for, the new order page was just meant as an example. I was wondering if there was a way of avoiding changing each controller by doing it in the routes. Seems there isn't.

Comment: Write a common method in application_controller and then call it via before filter in every controller you need to

Comment: This is what I went with. It works, but because the original request was a POST request, it doesn't seem like I can repeat it

Answer (score 0):

You need to override Devise's `after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)` method, you can do it in application controller

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  # new_order_path
end
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: Wouldn't that mean the user is always redirected to the new_order_path after sign in? There are multiple paths locked behind authentication, so i'd need this to be dynamic to the path the user was trying to reach.

Comment: Obviously, you need to add conditions for that!

Answer (score 0):

You can persist the last url - in session[:bookmark] and by doing something like this -

```
prepend_before_filter :set_bookmark

def set_bookmark
  session[:bookmark] = request.url
end
```

And within SessionsController, you can use value of session[:bookmark] if it exists or after_sign_in_path_for